# meteor Autosubscribe maintain certain documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm using autosubscribe to get a list of 50 latest chat documents in minimongo. As more messages are posted the older messages are removed from minimongo by autosubscribe. How can I get autosubscribe to not remove certain messages that I mark as active?

I know that I can just manually separately subscribe to a list of "active" messages but that seems unnecessarily laborious. Thanks.

Edit: the active marking is client side only, each user gets to choose the messages that he cares about, it's something ephemeral. The user's marking a the message as the one he's replying so, so it shouldn't be suddenly removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort on the time (_id captures the order it was inserted hence time) as well as with status, both in descending order.

Server code:

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function () {
    return Messages.find({}, {sort: {active: -1, _id:-1}, limit: 50});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the publish function, sort on status.

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function () {
    return Messages.find({}, {sort: {status: 1}, limit: 50});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your implementation is limited to a single user being able to mark a line active, then the marking of the chat-line document needs to use the active users [id](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_userid).

This sadly leads to the need for separate subscription even if it 'seems unnecessarily laborious'

Another 'laborious way' would be to make a local client-only collection copy of the selected active messages.

Comment: `Another 'laborious way' would be to make a local client-only collection copy of the selected active messages.` I've thought about this but it doesn't seem like it would work. It would cause a rerender wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Per client, maintain a session variable containing an array of marked doc IDs:

```
Session.set('markedMessages', matchedDocs)
```

Within your publish statement, use a $in statement that will match doc id's within the session array, combine this an $or statement to leverage your existing query, limit/slice.

```
Meteor.publish("markedMessages", function () {
  Messages.find({$or: [{ your_existing_query_goes_here }, 
    {_id: { $in: Session.get('markedMessages')}} ] }).fetch()
})
```

;

Note, within your handlebars template, compare the message id against your markedMessages Session to identify if the message was marked by the user.